# Writing 2d array into file that needs to look like array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have the following code that creates and writes to the file but it writes everything out in one solid line.

Example: 11111111111111111111111111

I need it look like the following(space in between every number):

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Here is my code:

```
public void saveFile()
{
   String save = "Testing";
   JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
   int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);


    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            FileWriter bw = new FileWriter(fc.getSelectedFile()+".txt");

            for(int row = 0; row < gameArray.length; row++)
           {
               for(int col =0; col < gameArray[row].length; col++)
               {

                  bw.write(String.valueOf(gameArray[row][col]));
                  System.out.println(gameArray[row][col] + " ");
                  System.out.println();
               }
           }
            bw.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Well yes, your code never writes out either a space or a line break. Think about where you'd want to write out a line break, and add that code. Then think about where you'd want to write out a space, and add that code.

Comment: I'ved tried what everybody recommended and in the file it is still printing out in a solid line.

Comment: My guess is you're on Windows, in which case you want `\r\n` instead of `\n` - or use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to find your system-specific line separator.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.  Why does it do this??

Comment: The characters used to indicate a line break differ by operating system, basically. It's very unfortunate :(

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not putting space between them.

```
bw.write(String.valueOf(gameArray[row][col]));
bw.write(" ");
```

and at the end of inner loop, again,

```
bw.write("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
public void saveFile()
{
   String save = "Testing";
   JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
   int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);


if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {
        FileWriter bw = new FileWriter(fc.getSelectedFile()+".txt");

        for(int row = 0; row < gameArray.length; row++)
       {
           for(int col =0; col < gameArray[row].length; col++)
           {

              bw.write(String.valueOf(gameArray[row][col]);
              if ((col+1)!=gameArray[row].length)
                 bw.write(" ");
              System.out.println(gameArray[row][col] + " ");
              System.out.println();
           }
              bw.write(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
       }
        bw.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This will leave a trailing space at the end of each line, which may not be ideal.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, totally forgot about that, fixed it.

Comment: Another possible problem is with `bw.write("\n");` We don't know on what OS this code will be executed so it is better not to use hardcoded line separators like `\n` but `System.lineSeparator()`

Answer (score 0):

write `bw.write("\n")` at the end of your inner loop.

Just like :

```
for(int row = 0; row < gameArray.length; row++)
       {
           for(int col =0; col < gameArray[row].length; col++)
           {

              bw.write(String.valueOf(gameArray[row][col]));
              System.out.println(gameArray[row][col] + " ");
              System.out.println();
           }
           bw.write("\n")
       }
```